# iconv_mime_decode failing on UTF-8

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm trying to find the best solution to work with any encoding charset (from Latin chars to Western Europe, to Chinese), and after doing some searchs on the internet, I came to this function:

```
function mime_encode($data)
{
    $resp = imap_utf8(trim($data));

    if(preg_match("/=\?/", $resp))
        $resp = iconv_mime_decode($data, ICONV_MIME_DECODE_CONTINUE_ON_ERROR, "ISO-8859-15");

    if(json_encode($resp) == 'null')
        $resp = utf8_encode($resp);

    return $resp;
}
```

As you see, it's using ISO-8859-15 to decode data, this is the first strange thing for me, because the original data is like this:

> =?utf-8?B?UHJlw4PCp29zIE9sw4PCoA==?=.txt //which is: Preços Olà.txt
>
> =?utf-8?B?w5DCkMOQwrrDkeKAmsOR4oKsw5DCuA==?=.txt //which is: Актри.txt
>
> =?utf-8?B?w5nigqzDmMKuw5nigqw=?=.txt //which is: ـخـ.txt

So, this shouldn't work with UTF-8 decode? Because when I change the iconv_mime_decode function to work with UTF-8 instead of that ISO, I get the output:

> "PreÃ§os OlÃ .txt"
>
> "ÐÐºÑ‚Ñ€Ð¸.txt"
>
> "Ù€Ø®Ù€.txt"

Ok, so I leave it with that ISO, but, the second one (the russian one), even when working with the ISO, I get the original data, instead of a decoded one:

> =?utf-8?B?w5DCkMOQwrrDkeKAmsOR4oKsw5DCuA==?=.txt

The other two are decoded nicely, but this russian one still mime encoded. What's happening here?